# How to load an image path in a css file placed in the public folder in laravel 5.4

Tags: html, css, laravel-5.4

I loaded a css file in my public file which is accessed by my blade files. but the problem is

```css
#heading-breadcrumbs{background:url('../img/banner_.jpg') 100% 100%;background-size:cover;padding:20px 0;margin-bottom:40px}#heading-breadcrumbs.no-mb{margin-bottom:0}#heading-breadcrumbs h1{color:#333;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:30px;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:.08em}@media(max-width:991px){#heading-breadcrumbs h1{text-align:center}}
```

It is not loading in my in views as my views is accessing the css file as

"http://greenrev.dev/assets/assets/img/banner_.jpg"

which is correct.

How can I fix this...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, just try to use this background:url('/img/banner_.jpg')